# How to combine Selected price and input checkbox price Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a checkout form . where there are 2 fields are used o give total amount of checkout  . 1 field is in select tag and second is input type check box i want when i select and option and checkbox there values should be combine to give total.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.price-input').change(function() {
    var price = 0;
    $('.price-input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        price += parseInt($(this).attr("value"), 10);
      }
    })
    $("select.price").change(function() {
      var selectedPrice = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
      document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = selectedPrice;
    });
    $(".totalPrice").text(price);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">@lang('Number of Words'):</label>
    <select class="price" name="word_prices_id" required>
      <option value="">@lang('Select Words')</option>
      @foreach($wordPrice as $wPrice)
      <option value="{{$wPrice->id}}">{{$wPrice->page_quantity}} words</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<input class="price-input" type="checkbox" name="upsell" value="12">
```

Comment: @calvin-nunes can you help ?

Comment: to be honest, I don't quite understood your question

Comment: sir, i have a checkout form . where there are 2 fields are used o give total amount of checkout  . 1 field is in <select > and second is input type check box i want when i select and option and checkbox there values should be combine to give total

Comment: How many .price-input checkbox are you expecting? With eventual different values, aren't you missing a multiplication here?

Comment: sir i am using foreach. so 1 is enought ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a class .ajx to both Select and input to handle changes made on both of their values in the same function !

```js
$(document).on('change', '.ajx', function () {
    if ($( "input.price-input:checked" ).is(":checked") && $("select.price").val()!==''){
    var price = 0;
    price += parseInt($("select.price").val(),10);
$('.price-input').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    price += parseInt($(this).attr("value"), 10);
  }
});
    $(".totalPrice").empty().text(price);
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Price:</label>
    <select class="price ajx" name="word_prices_id" required id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option value="">Choose Price</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<input class="price-input ajx" type="checkbox" name="upsell" value="12">
<input class="price-input ajx" type="checkbox" name="upsell1" value="15">
<div class="totalPrice">
</div>
```

Comment: not working . its working with only the values of select not combining both

Comment: User is expected to choose a quantity, that quantity is multiplied by the the value of the checkbox field (12 here) ! is that Right ?

Comment: no sir user will select price will be apply. checbox price will be added to product price as additional feature

Comment: Sorry I read quantity in your code, I understood it's a quantity and it should be multiplied. I updated it to perform an addition.

Comment: thanks alot sir but is ignoring foreach checkbox function and i am try to place each at different lines but not working

Comment: I asked you about it in a comment :) ok you can see the last update now..